# Resolved Promise not executing then function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm facing an issue where in my resolved promise is not executing the next chained `then`.

My code is like below

```
WordDocument.prototype.Open = function (data) {
        var _this = this;
        debugger;
        var that = this;
        var input = {
            onBeforeClose: function (data, callback) {
            },
            onBeforeSave: function (data, callback) {
                //alert('on Save');
                //this.Save(data);
            },
            path: "\\ElectronClient\\cm.doc"
        };
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        this.getDocument(data.docusId)
            .then(function (httpRes) {
                debugger;
                var response = JSON.parse(httpRes);
                return _this.saveDocumentInTemp(response);
            }).then(function (fileRes) {
                debugger;
                return _this.getInteropHandle(input);
            })["catch"](function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            })["finally"](function (f) {
                debugger;
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

The first `then` is executing perfectly fine..and `then` function is getting executed properly...but as you can see that I have returned the Promise of

```
_this.saveDocumentInTemp(response);
```

to the next chained `then`..but this second `then` is never getting executed..

The code for `_this.saveDocumentInTemp(response);` is like below:(not posting the exact code)

```
WordDocument.prototype.saveDocumentInTemp = function (response) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(true);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: There's nothing here that immediately seems amiss, unless there's an exception being thrown that isn't surfacing. Can you reproduce this in a jsbin or jsfiddle? Creating a small reproducible example will help us help you better (and may reveal the issue at play here)

Comment: your code looks mostly fine. Note that you aren't resolving the first deferred, but this should not be the cause of your problem.

Comment: are you sure your `WordDocument.prototype.saveDocumentInTemp` is resolving correctly? If the subsequent `then` statements are not resolving, then it might be the promise that is returning from `WordDocument.prototype.saveDocumentInTemp`

Comment: Try just `return Q.resolve(true)`. Or really just `return true` since you're not doing async